# Spectre performance hit disappeared after April 2018 Update?

Tags: windows, performance, security, windows-10, spectre

We are tracking the performance issue of Meltdown and Spectre mitigations on Windows for several months now. Several days ago, we found some weird results. After applying April 2018 Cumulative Update (KB4093112) on our Windows 10 FCU machine, all of sudden, the performance hit we observed until now disappeared and all benchmark we run returned to the same level when the mitigations are not applied.

For example, below is the GDI performance number reported by CrystalMark 2004R3 (We ran several benchmarks plus our own application benchmark, all resulting in performance numbers back to pre-Meltdown/Spectre level)

```
Win10 FCU Vanilla (no Meltdown/Spectre mitigations    ~14000
Win10 FCU + KB4056892 (Jan 2018 Cum Update)            ~5400
Win10 FCU + KB4074588 (Feb 2018 Cum Update)            ~5400
Win10 FCU + KB4088776 (Mar 2018 Cum Update)            ~5400
Win10 FCU + KB4093112 (Apr 2018 Cum Update)           ~14000 (<- back to Vanilla level)
```

Machine is an HP Z840 with Xeon E52690 v4 x 2 (total 28 cores). BIOS is updated with v2.41 of SP85295 update from https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05869091.

Using https://www.grc.com/inspectre.htm, I have checked that the flags to enable Meltdown/Spectre are in place.

Does anyone know the reason of this behavior ? I doubt that the mitigations can be suddenly improved back to the level of when no mitigations are applied. Is there any chance Microsoft accidentally disabled the mitigations with Apr 2018 Cumulative update ?

Answer (score 1):

See this discussion inspired by your post:
https://www.administrator.de/content/detail.php?id=371913&token=127#comment-1279796

Comment: Thanks for the info. From what I experienced, the Spectre2 mitigations mostly effect scenarios that involves system calls (GDI is one, others are disk access, memory allocations, and maybe networks). This is because they need to put barrier-like semantics to avoid branch targets learned in user mode to affect branch prediction behavior in the kernel mode. That's why Matlab workloads are not impacted because they are compute-intensive. Ref: https://www.zdnet.com/article/linux-and-intel-slowly-hack-their-way-to-a-spectre-patch/

Comment: quotes from the link: https://www.zdnet.com/article/linux-and-intel-slowly-hack-their-way-to-a-spectre-patch/

The third feature (IBRS) is more complicated. It's designed to be set when you enter a more privileged execution mode (i.e. the kernel). It prevents branch targets learned in a less-privileged execution mode, BEFORE IT WAS MOST RECENTLY SET, from taking effect. But it's not just a 'set-and-forget' feature, it also has barrier-like semantics and needs to be set on *each* entry into the kernel (from userspace or a VM guest). It's *also* expensive.